# Editable select

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="editable-select-holder">
    <input type="text" name="position" id="position" value="${userInfoForm.position}">
    <button type="button" class="editable-select-expander"></button>
    <ul class="editable-select-options">
        <c:forEach var="position" items="${positions}">
            <li>${position.description}</li>
        </c:forEach>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and this is Jquery:

```
$(document).on('click', '.editable-select-expander', function () {
    var $holder = $(this).parent();
    $holder.toggleClass('editable-select-expanded');
    $holder.on('click', 'li', function () {
        var $t = $(this);
        $holder.removeClass('editable-select-expanded');
        $holder.find('input').val($t.text());
    });
});
```

I want to exand list when I click on button or focus on input. The code I have provided above only works on button click. I need the same logic also on focus event. Any suggestions?

changed like this but still not working properly.

```
 $(document).on("click",'.editable-select-holder', function() {
                var $holder = $(this);
                $holder.on('click','.editable-select-expander', function() {
                    $holder.toggleClass('editable-select-expanded');
                });

                $holder.on('click', 'li', function() {
                    var $t = $(this);

                    $holder.removeClass('editable-select-expanded');

                    $holder.find('input').val($t.text());
                });

                $holder.on('focus', 'input', function() {
                    $holder.addClass('editable-select-expanded');
                });
            });
```

Comment: Add `tabindex` attribute to all `li`s in order to make them focusable.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you can use this code

```
  $( your input box id or class ).focusin(function() {
  //your logic here
  });
```